# [Java Web]The project post NULL pointer errors while running in server

Tags: java, android, servlets

Thanks for reading.

I'm asking for my friends who is developing a WeChat project and don't wanna use English to post questions.

Preliminary talked with him,I have some basic understanding of what he's doing.He wants to deploy the project on Sina Cloud server and visit his project from the cloud server.Here's the core code:

eclipse-jee-neon-3-win32-x86_64
tomcat8
Servlet.java

```
package com.weixin.servlet;    
import java.io.IOException;    
import java.io.PrintWriter;    
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;    
import com.weixin.util.Util;

public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {      

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String signature=req.getParameter("signature");
        String timestamp=req.getParameter("timestamp");
        String nonce=req.getParameter("nonce");
        String echostr=req.getParameter("echostr");         

        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        if(Util.checkSignature(signature, timestamp, nonce)){
            out.print(echostr);
        }       
    }    
}
```

Util.java

```
package com.weixin.util;

import java.security.MessageDigest;    
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Util {
    private static final String token="stitch";
    public static boolean checkSignature(String signature,String timestamp,String nonce){
        String[] arr =new String[]{token,timestamp,nonce};
        //sort
            Arrays.sort(arr);           

        //genarate String
        StringBuffer content=new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            content.append(arr[i]);
        }

        //sha1 encryption
        String temp =getSha1(content.toString()); 
        return temp.equals(signature);
    }

    public static String getSha1(String str){
        if (null == str || 0 == str.length()){
            return null;
        }

        char[] hexDigits = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 
                'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
        try {
            MessageDigest mdTemp = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
            mdTemp.update(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            byte[] md = mdTemp.digest();
            int j = md.length;
            char[] buf = new char[j * 2];
            int k = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                byte byte0 = md[i];
                buf[k++] = hexDigits[byte0 >>> 4 & 0xf];
                buf[k++] = hexDigits[byte0 & 0xf];
            }

            return new String(buf);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        } 
    }
}

Web.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Wx</display-name>

  <servlet>
       <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.weixin.servlet.Servlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/wx.do</url-pattern>     
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

When the project was run on server:
The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling 
the request.

> Java.lang.NullPointerException
>       javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.Tst2.ShaServlet
>           org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>           org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>           org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>           org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
>           org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>           org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>           org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
>           org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>           org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>           java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Root Cause
>       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Tst2.ShaServlet
>           org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
>           org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
>           org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>           org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>           org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>           org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
>           org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>           org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>           org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
>           org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>           org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>           java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

**Question(quote exactly from developer):**

1.How to apply WeChat appid?

2.How to deploy the server?

Comment: Please provide minimal and to the problem reduced code. And, btw, it hasn't anything to do with the question who actually wanted to know the answer.

Comment: Umm..thanks. I've already found that his welcome file lacks a tag.Anyway thank you for your tip.